# A simple apparatus to detect whether my ear touches a metal plate lying on the floor

Tags: basic

For the sake of simplicity, I just want to create a simple apparatus that produces blinks when doing push-up exercises. However, in the future, I will probably combine this system with a digital counter.

A metal plate is laid on the floor. When I touch the plate with my ear, the bulb will turn on. How to setup such a apparatus?

I have:

- battery
- bulb 3 volt
- metal plate
- cables

Making battery, bulb, my body and plate in series might be the simplest way, but I am not sure the voltage of battery needed. Is it safe? Is there any better way?

Comment: #offtopic: What kind of pushups are done with ear touching the floor??

Comment: Why is it a metal plate?

Comment: [This capacitive sensing circuit from electronicdesign.com](http://electronicdesign.com/analog/capacitive-proximity-sensor-provides-accuracy-and-speed) works fine, although for counting you would have to take care of metastability of the flip-flop.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Touching your left and right ears to the metal plate alternately can help us to maintain a correct body position during push-up exercise. Let's try it by yourself. :-)

Comment: @Andyaka: Because I need a conductor to make a closed loop.

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple touch sensor circuit should do the job.  I recommend a Darlington pair rather than a simple transistor

[image: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/images/Touch_sensor_schematic.jpg]
from http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-build-a-touch-sensor-circuit

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to make contact with the skin of your ear, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

The problem is that, if you make contact to the plate with your ear, all of the bulb current must flow through your skin, and skin resistance is usually [high enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_shock) that a 3-volt bulb will not get enough current to light for any reasonable supply voltage. [Here, for instance](http://www.lightexports.com/pr30-krypton-flashlight-bulb-p13-5s-3-75v-b3-5/?gclid=Cj0KEQjw4NmvBRCRp_yu2bzal4YBEiQAWfjpJnZcX-u3A2TVtdqR20s1e4a3btPm0WnTwfwIveR4MLwaAmWT8P8HAQ) is a flashlight bulb for sale, and it draws 0.86 amps. Even if you were soaking wet (good workout, right?) with a skin resistance of 1000 ohms, $$ i(current) = \frac{V(volts)}{R(resistance)}$$ so you'd need 860 volts. On the one hand, you wouldn't need to be able to see the bulb to know that you'd made contact with the plate. On the other hand, you'd be unconscious and wouldn't know you'd made contact with the plate. Well, actually you'd probably be dead.

If you still want to try this setup, you could always make a clamp that would attach a wire to your ear, and make contact with the plate with the clamp. In this case a 3-volt battery would work fine and there would be no danger of shock. For that matter, depending on what piercings you have in your ears already the whole thing might be pretty easy. Your circuit would look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foSZV2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the clamp (held by the ear) touches the plate, the bulb will light up.

As a plus, if you don't have any existing piercings to repurpose as contacts, any clamp which will stay in place will be pretty uncomfortable, and this will inspire you to do your pushups quickly.